# Path '/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have this in my base controller

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
    {
        return;
    }

    var logger = new Logger();
    logger.LogError(filterContext.Exception, ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString());

    filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
    {
        ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml",
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary()
        {
            {"exception", filterContext.Exception}
        }
    };
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
}
```

and I definitely have a file at

```
Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
```

[image]

But whenever an unhandled exception occurs, I get this error in the log

> Path '/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml' was not found.

But according to [this article](https://stackify.com/aspnet-mvc-error-handling/) this should work...

How is this possible?

Comment: That's strange. However seems that `ViewData` initializing to new object may be the reason of this behaviour. Just to confirm this can you make the  one of the change --- 1) Return the ViewResult with ViewData 2) instead of creating new ViewResult object,  define it as `filterContext.Result = this.View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml", filterContext.Exception)`.  The exception object passed to View, can be accessed by `ViewData.Model` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you dont need the full name hear because its the default page. Just try

```
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
{
    ViewName = "Error",
    ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary()
    {
        {"exception", filterContext.Exception}
    }
};
```

I hope this works for you!